# How to compute checksum of some binary function (or basic block) after compilation?

Tags: c++, security, binary, x86, obfuscation

I want to program some simple tamperproofing mechanism that computes at runtime a checksum of some function (or basic block) and compares it to a fixed precomputed value. If the checksum matches, then everything is fine; otherwise the program terminates.

I can easily compute the checksum at runtime, but I don't know how to compute the fixed value for comparison.

I guess I've to do some post processing on the binary after compilation, since it is impossible to know the checksum at compile time (right?).

But how would I locate the code point in the binary code that corresponds to my function (or basic block)? I could possible do this manually using some hex editor, but I'd like to automate the process. After having precomputed the checksum, I'd need to modify the binary to include the it - but this again requires being able to find the proper location in the binary.

Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Looks to me like you'll have a bad time. There's more than one way to compile a function in c++, so there's no predefined way to precompute an expected value. Maybe an interpreted language would suit your task better?

Comment: Thanks, but that's why I am suggesting to make some post-processing.

Comment: @Shuzheng What do you want to achieve actually? Maybe there's a better approach than doing that within the executable/shared library.

Comment: I want to achieve implementing a tamperproof mechanism.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info ?

Comment: @Jesper Yeah, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Just checking a checksum of your code at runtime against a predefined value is not going to make it tamperproof. That's going to take all of 5minutes with a hex editor/debugger to bypass.

Comment: I know, but I do it just for fun.

Comment: You will need to prove to yourself that the code you checksum is the code being called from the call-site.  If the code in question is in-lined then no copy of it as a function will exist UNTIL you take it's address.  Then the linker will preserve one copy of the function. BUT this copy is not the one being run from the call-site (as it was in-lined).  Modifications to the in-lined version will not be detected.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a pointer to function and reinterpret it as array of uint8_t, for example. Also you could disable inlining for particular function, if you don't want compiler to use inlined copy of that function in some loop.

```
uint8_t* pMain = (uint8_t*)&main;
```

Then you have to try estimate of function length and compute checksum.

Comment: However, to perform this you have to modify source code before compilation.

Answer (score 0):

If your code consists of several files you could following mechanism:

1. compile files with functions you want to check in the future
2. locate in compiled files (most likely .o, .obj) function locations - for example using objdump or similar tool - it must display both human readable text as well as hex codes of compiled code

example:

> objdump  a.o -d --insn-width=10

```
  40064b:       48 89 e5                        mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40064e:       ff d0                           callq  *%rax
  400650:       5d                              pop    %rbp
  400651:       e9 7a ff ff ff                  jmpq   4005d0 <register_tm_clones>

0000000000400656 <calculate>:
  400656:       55                              push   %rbp
  400657:       48 89 e5                        mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40065a:       89 7d ec                        mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  40065d:       48 89 75 e0                     mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  400661:       8b 05 f9 09 20 00               mov    0x2009f9(%rip),%eax        # 601060 <magicCRC1>
  400667:       89 c2                           mov    %eax,%edx
  400669:       48 8b 45 e0                     mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  40066d:       89 10                           mov    %edx,(%rax)
  40066f:       48 8b 45 e0                     mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  400673:       48 83 c0 04                     add    $0x4,%rax
  400677:       c7 00 01 00 00 00               movl   $0x1,(%rax)
  40067d:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00            movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  400684:       eb 72                           jmp    4006f8 <calculate+0xa2>
  400686:       83 7d fc 01                     cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  40068a:       75 1c                           jne    4006a8 <calculate+0x52>
  40068c:       8b 45 fc                        mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  40068f:       48 98                           cltq
```

so in case of objdump function name will be surrounded by < > - above example for calculate function

3. write script to parse it - you need hex codes between address and disassembled code
4. calculate your CRC, hash or whatever you need
5. store CRC as well as block length to decode later at runtime it in a file which than will be compiled too - of course you need to know mapping what variable/constant hold which function CRC
6. link all files

In case of single file available (complete executable) you may:

1. define constants/statics in source code to hold CRC
2. do CRC calculation as described above
3. locate your var location in binary (in .data or .rodata section) and update it
4. most likely you than need to fix executable CRC too!

Comment: Thanks @Anty. Can you recommend any premade parser? By "executable CRC" you mean the checksum of the executable itself, right?